# Dell Precision 380 does not accept RAM

Tags: memory, dell-precision

I have Dell Precision 380. It has 512 MB RAM.

Now I want to add a  NANYA 0639 1 GB RAM but it does not accept that by showing diagnosing *CODE 3,4* and beeps.

Please anyone suggest me some solution accordingly.

Comment: The machine supports `Up to 8GB dual-channel DDR2 533MHz ECC registered memory; Four DIMM slots; 667MHz and non-ECC memory also available`. Can you add a picture or show information of the RAM module?

Comment: Have you checked that the RAM is compatible with the motherboard?
[Crucial](http://www.crucial.com/) have great tools to assist with this.

Comment: @tombull89 Man! I have doubt that memory slots are rusty...! how can I clean rust from slots? Can I use Petrol to clean the rust of slots or kindly you suggest me other tip or trick! Thank you!

Comment: @ArshadAli rusty? jeeze...white spirit or a cleaning solvent, maybe?

Comment: @tombull89 I tried several times to check if RAM works of not? during this RAM has damaged and  [this is](http://i58.tinypic.com/14w3wpk.png) what  the red highlighted area which is free from one side and bit attached from other. Now how can I set that if you have any suggestions Please.